# Get distances between boundaries from an SpatialPolygon and raster pixels

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, raster, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the distance from several pixels of a raster to a boundary of some polygons in R as it is showed in the image. I have two problems:

1. How to correctly define a boundary from a `SpatialPolygon` object. I currently have two options, but I can not decide for which is the best one. First, I can coerce the `SpatialPolygon` `as` a `SpatialLines` object and then to SpatialPoints. Second, I can `raster::rasterize` the `SpatialPolygon`. I suppose each option has its pros and cons.
2. I only want make the distance calculation from one of the sides of the border. In the example, I only want the distance to the border from the pixels inside Colombia to the border between both countries. I tried to "filter" the border using a latitude parameter but the real border is quite irregular, so using a strict cut-off value can lead to error.

The following code can be used to get the an example `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`:

```
#Get the world map and select two countries [Colombia and Venezuela]
library(maptools) #To get the polygon data 
data(wrld_simpl)
colven <- c("Colombia", "Venezuela")
colven_map <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME %in% colven, ]
```

Raster data can be created with this code:

```
library(raster)
raster <- raster(colven_map, nrow=100, ncol=100)
raster[] <- 1:length(raster)
raster_colven <- mask(raster, colven_map)
```

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your image is not showing up.

Comment: Please ask a good R question: create a self-contained reproducible example and show some code

Comment: I modify the question and added some code snippets to get SpatialPolygon data and a raster. Thanks for your recommendation Robert.

Answer (score 1):

```
#example data
library(maptools) #To get the polygon data 
data(wrld_simpl)
colven <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME %in% c("Colombia", "Venezuela"), ]

library(raster)
raster <- raster(colven, nrow=100, ncol=100)
raster[] <- 1:length(raster)
raster <- mask(raster, colven)
```

I create some random cells of interest

```
set.seed(33)
cells <- sample(ncell(raster), 10)
xy <- xyFromCell(raster, cells)
sp <- SpatialPoints(xy, proj4string=crs(colven))
```

And then use rgeos

```
library(rgeos)
# inside Colombia only
col <- colven[colven$NAME == "Colombia", ]
sp <- gIntersection(sp, col)

# get the border between Venezuela and Colombia
ven <- colven[colven$NAME == "Venezuela", ]
border <- gIntersection(col, ven)

# get the distance
# this fails for me, that seems to be a bug in rgeos for these data
gDistance(sp, border, byid=TRUE)
```

In this example the coordinate reference system is angular (longitude/latitude) and rgeos does not deal with that (it only works well for planar coordinates). But here you can use a function from geosphere:

```
library(geosphere)
dist2Line(xy, border)
```

If you want the distance form all grid cell of Colombia to the border you can also do:

```
rborder <- rasterize(border,  raster)
dborder <- distance(rborder)
dbcol <- mask(dborder, col)
```

See functions in the `gdistance` package if you want the distance from a place within Colombia to the border with Venezuela, while only travelling within Colombia.

Comment: `d <- gDistance(polygon, p)` is going to calculate the distance from every pixel (now point) to the boundary or to polygon's centroid? 

Well, what I want is to have the distance to the red border, not to the blue one. The pixels inside the polygon or the distance between the pixels outside the polygon and the blue border are not of my interest.

Comment: Robert, I added a lot more detail and a reproducible code without having to download anything. I did this on the premise that this post can help others with similar problems and to make my questions more understandable. Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, that is the idea.

Comment: `reos::gIntersect` is giving me several error because the complexity (I think) of the intersection between the polygons. Can I mask the raster from one of the sides: `col_raster <- mask(raster, col)` and calculate the distance to the border with `ven`? I was thinking also a Convex hull to "simplify" the polygons, but that is not a good solution.